# Compare ID's (new, existing, dropped) over time

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Your expertise is much appreciated. Here is my problem, we have a table with monthly snapshots that includes an ID and a snapshot date:

```
    ID,Snapshot_Date
    1,Dec-17
    2,Dec-17
    3,Dec-17
    1,Jan-18
    3,Jan-18
    4,Jan-18
    3,Feb-18
    5,Feb-18
    6,Feb-18
```

The requirement is to be able to report in any given month (usually the most recent) that we started out [some month and year] with x IDs, we lost Y IDs and gained Z IDs.

One logic for the SQL query is to return all months, all IDs and their status, 0=carried over,+1=new,-1=dropped. Note how ID=2 is dropped from Feb-18 because we noted it dropped in Jan-18 in the results:

```
    Snapshot_Date,ID,Status
    Dec-17,1,+1
    Dec-17,2,+1
    Dec-17,3,+1
    Jan-18,1,0
    Jan-18,2,-1
    Jan-18,3,0
    Jan-18,4,+1
    Feb-18,1,-1
    Feb-18,3,0
    Feb-18,4,0
    Feb-18,5,+1
```

Comment: And how do you know that `id` 1 dropped in January?  I only see records of creation.

Comment: Each month is a snapshot, so id 1 was created in Dec and was also included in the Jan snapshot, so it was carried over. Sorry for the poorly formed problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data model that has to be built for answering such kind of questions is based on all possible combinations of ID and time unit, i.e. you need to create a record for every ID at every month in your case and say whether this ID is present on this month or not, and the same for the previous month. The proof of concept would look like this:

```
WITH
 ids as (
    select distinct id from your_table
)
,months as (
    select distinct snapshot_date from your_table
)
,id_month_pairs as (
    select *
    from ids
    cross join months
)
,id_months as (
    select *
    ,(your_table.id is not null) as is_present_this_month
    ,lag(your_table.id is not null) over (partition by id order by to_date(snapshot_date,'Mon-YY')) as is_present_prev_month
    from id_month_pairs
    left join your_table
    using (id, snapshot_date)
)
select 
 snapshot_date as month
,sum(case when is_present_this_month and is_present_prev_month then 1 else 0 end) as carried_over
,sum(case when is_present_this_month and not is_present_prev_month then 1 else 0 end) as gained
,sum(case when not is_present_this_month and is_present_prev_month then 1 else 0 end) as lost
from id_months
group by 1
order by to_date(snapshot_date,'Mon-YY')
```

in reality, what you can do is materialize `id_months` step at a new table (do ELT in Redshift), converting text month to date month and adding other useful dimensions, and run the aggregation step separately against this table.

P.S. selecting distinct and cross joining to get `id_months` is not optimal, this is just to show the general idea. You can have month dates table and join it to the ID list so that records start only from the first month the ID is present, not all month/id pairs. But I'm leaving this to you:)